# Visual Studio 2012 cannot connect to Team Foundation service unless the Fiddler is opened?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fiddler, azure-devops

Up until recently, everything worked just fine.

However, now, I can no longer connect to Team Foundation Service unless the Fiddler is opened?!
A couple days ago, I've setup the Fiddler according to the configuration tips [DecryptHttpS](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS) and [tip2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/06/05/configure-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-work-with-fiddler.aspx) and the issues began to occur.

This is the message I get when I try to connect.

[image]

I've tried

- turning off decrypt https
- removing all Fiddler certificates
- uninstalling Fiddler
- removing all cookies from IE
- ...

and many other things that crossed my mind, but with no success.
Seems like VS just can't get to TFS without it.

Meanwhile, I can view the TFS perfectly from browser. (And yes, opening a new instance of VS from home page of TFS doesn't work either)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally managed to get to the bottom of this.
The issue was caused by the following entry in the machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
      <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Once I got rid of it, everything started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this would indicate that the client is configured to use a proxy at `127.0.0.1:8888` even when Fiddler isn't running. Typically, .NET clients get their proxy settings from the system whenever they start.

Without Fiddler running, what are your proxy settings inside IE's Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings?

If you start Fiddler, then untick File > Capture Traffic, *then* start your TFS client, do you see Fiddler capturing the client's requests even though capture is disabled?

Comment: You're quite right. Fiddler continues to capture traffic only for Visual Studio even when the Capture is turned off. No proxy is set in IE settings. Could this command `prefs set fiddler.network.proxy.registrationhostname HostName` be the cause? Is there are way to revert it?

Comment: The Pref in question only controls how Fiddler registers as the system proxy ("127.0.0.1" vs. other); it doesn't control anything else (If you want to remove it anyway, call via `prefs remove fiddler.network.proxy.registrationhostname`). To resolve the issue reported, we need to figure out *where* the VS process is caching outdated proxy information. I assume you've rebooted at least once (without Fiddler running)?

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted multiple times since the issue started and every time the fiddler was already turned off.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2012 does not make this easy. Try the following.
1. Shut down VS
2. Open IE
3. Clear your cache
4. Shut down IE
5. Open VS

In VS 2013, you would need to remove the URL from the connection dialog and re-add it.