# TF30063: You are not authorized to access IP

Tags: tfs

I am using below code to connect my tfs where executing machine is part of domain.

But when I try the same code in different machine (not in domain, but part of work group) getting unauthorized access error.

***But in the same machine (where getting error), I am able to connect TFS with same account used in code via visual studio.***

```
  var tfsServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(
      new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFS_URI"]),
      new NetworkCredential(
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSUserName"], 
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSPassword"], 
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on getting the network credential specified properly. I'd suggest using Fiddler to take a look at what VS is sending and what your code is sending.

Comment: Visual studio activities like checkin/out, GetLatestVersion are captured by Fiddler. My code calls to tfs using tfs api, not captured.

Comment: See the top answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498863/visual-studio-2012-cannot-connect-to-team-foundation-service-unless-the-fiddler. It's bypassing the proxy, which Fiddler needs to capture the traffic.